# Android Studio 1.4: some text and interface is corrupted

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded yesterday Android Studio 1.4. Its font is some places looks on pic below so it's impossible to read it. How to fix it? Has anyone the same problem?
Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Font settings in my Android Studio:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change that you have to do the folllowing. In your android studio go to
`files-->settings-->Editor-->colors & Fonts-->fonts` there are other options below it change the schema to a different one change options and save it apply

Comment: thank for reply. but on what change? there is set default settings in colors & Fonts-->fonts!